# What does ^ sign mean on a vector?

Tags: notation, vectors

I have a maths homework question
Given the vector b find  bˆ

The symbol is actually above the b, but I am not sure what it means. Guessing it means to find the unit vector of b?

Comment: Yes, that's correct: $\hat b$ often denotes $b/|b|$ (for $b$ nonzero).

Comment: You can write $\hat b$ like so: \$\hat b\$. If you like bold vectors (*i.e.*, $\hat{\mathbb b}$), then write: \$\hat{\mathbb b}\$.

Comment: To typeset it, you can use `\hat` to put the hat over the next symbol. so `$\hat b$` gives $\hat b$. And `$\hat{words}$` gives $\hat{words}$.

Comment: Also, for i and j use `$\hat\imath, \hat\jmath$` to get $\hat\imath, \hat\jmath$ rather than $\hat i, \hat j$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is a common notation for the "unit vector in the direction of $b$". That is,
$$
\hat b = \frac{1}{\|b\|} \cdot b
$$